# If $f$ is one to one show that $f(a) \in \partial \Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Let $G$ be a region. Let $a \in G$. Suppose that $f:(G-{a}) \to \mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function such that $f(G-{a})=\Omega$ is bounded.

i) Show that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$

ii) If $f$ is one to one, then $f(a) \in \partial \Omega$

My try: 
$$ \text{The first part is easy for} \lim_{z \to a}|z-a||f(z)|=0$$

For the second part, $f$ can be extended to analytic function in $G$ and moreover $f(a)$ cannot lie in $\Omega$ (if it did then it would violate its one-one ness).  Therefore all we have to show that $f(a) \not \in \Omega ^{c}$. Suppose it did,  then there exists $r \gt 0$ such that $|f(z)-f(a)| \gt r$ for all $z$ in $G$.  Now $a$ is a removable singularity of $f$, so there exists a $\delta \gt 0$ such that $B(a,\delta) \subset G$ and $f$ is analytic in $B(a,\delta)$ . Choose $z_n \in B(a,\dfrac{\delta}{n})$. Then $z_n \to a$ must imply that $f(z_n) \to f(a)$ but this is a contradiction as $|f(z_n)-f(a)| \gt r$.

Is this alright??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It looks ok to me. Where you write ...,so there exists a $\delta > 0$... etc. I would have written $F$ or $\widetilde{f}$ or something like this because it's an analytic extension of $f$ and not $f$ itself (as it is defined at $a$ and $f$ isn't).

Comment: "For the second part, f can be extended to analytic function in G and moreover f(a) cannot lie in Ω (if it did then it would violate its one-one ness)" It would violate its 1-1 ness in $G\setminus \{a\}$? Why?

Comment: Suppose $ f (a)= g \in  \Omega $ , since $ g $ is already in $\Omega $, there exists a $ g_0$ in $ G $ such that $ f (g_0)=g$  and then it follows

Comment: @zhw. I am pinging on behalf of OP.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam It's not helpful to denote elements in $\Omega$ by $g$.

Comment: @zhw. THe argument I had in mind when I first read this post was that since $f$ is injective, if $f(a)$ was in $f(G-a)$ then $f(a) = f(b)$ for some $b$ in $G-a$ thereby contradicting injectivity of $f$.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam  In ii) I was assuming we are given only that $f$ is 1-1 on $G\setminus \{a\}.$